# How to end this program when user inputs "end"?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

So basically I am trying to figure out how to stop this program using `Integer.valueOf(String s)` or `Integer.parseInt(String s)` by typing "end" for the user input

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class monkey1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int lol = 1;
        do { 
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            lol = s.nextInt();
            sum += lol;
            if (lol > 0) {
                System.out.println("Sum is now: " + sum);
            }
        } while (lol>0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - you need to change `lol=sc.nextInt()` to `String tmp = s.nextLine()`

Second - do

```
try {
   if (tmp.equals("END")) {
       break;  // This will exit do-while loop
   }
   lol = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  // Here you can also exit loop by adding break. Or just ask user to enter new text.
}
```

Comment: can you help and suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename

Answer (score 1):

you should learn how to use try/catch.
Here we go:

```
String text = "";
    int lol = 1;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        text = s.nextLine();
        try {
            lol = Integer.valueOf(text);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exit");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code

```
package Phone;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class monkey1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int hi = 1;
        do { 
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            String lol = s.nextLine();
            if(lol.equals("end")) {
                break;
        }

        hi = Integer.parseInt(lol);

        sum += hi;
        if (hi > 0) {
            System.out.println("Sum is now: " + sum);
        }
    } while (hi > 0);
}
```

What I did here is I changed lol to hi for adding and took String input so that you can input end...

Comment: can you help and suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking if s.equals("end") before converting to int so something like this:

```
do { 
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        String userValue = s.nextLine();
        if(userValue.equals("end")
            break;
        lol = Integer.parseInt(userValue);
        sum += lol;
        if (lol > 0){
            System.out.println("Sum is now: " + sum);
        }
    }while (lol>0);
```

Comment: Please note that this example will fail with `NumberFormatException` in case if user will enter text other than `end` and that is not a number.

Comment: Yes,important note @VladislavVarslavans , it was taken for granted that user will provide correct input.